# Missing roles in Windows Server 2016

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-server-2016, nps

I'm trying to install the NPS role on Windows Server 2016 (Datacenter) but neither Server Manager nor Install-Windows feature seem to be aware of its existence:

[image]

```
PS > Install-WindowsFeature NPAS -IncludeManagementTools
Install-WindowsFeature : ArgumentNotValid: The role, role service, or feature name is not valid: 'NPAS'. The name was
not found.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (NPAS:String) [Install-WindowsFeature], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NameDoesNotExist,Microsoft.Windows.ServerManager.Commands.AddWindowsFeatureCommand

Success Restart Needed Exit Code      Feature Result
------- -------------- ---------      --------------
False   No             InvalidArgs    {}
```

There are a number of other roles that are missing like Fax Server and Windows Deployment Services.

Is there something else that needs to be done to install it (and the other missing roles)?

**UPDATE:** The output of `Get-WindowsFeature`

```
PS > Get-Windowsfeature -computername domain | where {$_.Installed -eq $false}

Display Name                                            Name                       Install State
------------                                            ----                       -------------
[ ] Active Directory Certificate Services               AD-Certificate                 Available
    [ ] Certification Authority                         ADCS-Cert-Authority            Available
    [ ] Certificate Enrollment Policy Web Service       ADCS-Enroll-Web-Pol            Available
    [ ] Certificate Enrollment Web Service              ADCS-Enroll-Web-Svc            Available
    [ ] Certification Authority Web Enrollment          ADCS-Web-Enrollment            Available
    [ ] Network Device Enrollment Service               ADCS-Device-Enrollment         Available
    [ ] Online Responder                                ADCS-Online-Cert               Available
[ ] Active Directory Federation Services                ADFS-Federation                Available
[ ] Active Directory Lightweight Directory Services     ADLDS                          Available
[ ] Active Directory Rights Management Services         ADRMS                          Available
    [ ] Active Directory Rights Management Server       ADRMS-Server                   Available
    [ ] Identity Federation Support                     ADRMS-Identity                 Available
[ ] Device Health Attestation                           DeviceHealthAttestat...        Available
        [ ] BranchCache for Network Files               FS-BranchCache                 Available
        [ ] Data Deduplication                          FS-Data-Deduplication          Available
        [ ] DFS Namespaces                              FS-DFS-Namespace               Available
        [ ] DFS Replication                             FS-DFS-Replication             Available
        [ ] File Server Resource Manager                FS-Resource-Manager            Available
        [ ] File Server VSS Agent Service               FS-VSS-Agent                   Available
        [ ] iSCSI Target Server                         FS-iSCSITarget-Server          Available
        [ ] iSCSI Target Storage Provider (VDS and V... iSCSITarget-VSS-VDS            Available
        [ ] Server for NFS                              FS-NFS-Service                 Available
        [ ] Work Folders                                FS-SyncShareService            Available
[ ] Host Guardian Service                               HostGuardianServiceRole        Available
[ ] Hyper-V                                             Hyper-V                        Available
[ ] Network Controller                                  NetworkController              Available
[ ] Print and Document Services                         Print-Services                 Available
    [ ] Print Server                                    Print-Server                   Available
    [ ] LPD Service                                     Print-LPD-Service              Available
[ ] Remote Access                                       RemoteAccess                   Available
    [ ] DirectAccess and VPN (RAS)                      DirectAccess-VPN               Available
    [ ] Routing                                         Routing                        Available
    [ ] Web Application Proxy                           Web-Application-Proxy          Available
[ ] Remote Desktop Services                             Remote-Desktop-Services        Available
    [ ] Remote Desktop Connection Broker                RDS-Connection-Broker          Available
    [ ] Remote Desktop Licensing                        RDS-Licensing                  Available
    [ ] Remote Desktop Virtualization Host              RDS-Virtualization             Available
[ ] Volume Activation Services                          VolumeActivation               Available
[ ] Web Server (IIS)                                    Web-Server                     Available
    [ ] Web Server                                      Web-WebServer                  Available
        [ ] Common HTTP Features                        Web-Common-Http                Available
            [ ] Default Document                        Web-Default-Doc                Available
            [ ] Directory Browsing                      Web-Dir-Browsing               Available
            [ ] HTTP Errors                             Web-Http-Errors                Available
            [ ] Static Content                          Web-Static-Content             Available
            [ ] HTTP Redirection                        Web-Http-Redirect              Available
            [ ] WebDAV Publishing                       Web-DAV-Publishing             Available
        [ ] Health and Diagnostics                      Web-Health                     Available
            [ ] HTTP Logging                            Web-Http-Logging               Available
            [ ] Custom Logging                          Web-Custom-Logging             Available
            [ ] Logging Tools                           Web-Log-Libraries              Available
            [ ] ODBC Logging                            Web-ODBC-Logging               Available
            [ ] Request Monitor                         Web-Request-Monitor            Available
            [ ] Tracing                                 Web-Http-Tracing               Available
        [ ] Performance                                 Web-Performance                Available
            [ ] Static Content Compression              Web-Stat-Compression           Available
            [ ] Dynamic Content Compression             Web-Dyn-Compression            Available
        [ ] Security                                    Web-Security                   Available
            [ ] Request Filtering                       Web-Filtering                  Available
            [ ] Basic Authentication                    Web-Basic-Auth                 Available
            [ ] Centralized SSL Certificate Support     Web-CertProvider               Available
            [ ] Client Certificate Mapping Authentic... Web-Client-Auth                Available
            [ ] Digest Authentication                   Web-Digest-Auth                Available
            [ ] IIS Client Certificate Mapping Authe... Web-Cert-Auth                  Available
            [ ] IP and Domain Restrictions              Web-IP-Security                Available
            [ ] URL Authorization                       Web-Url-Auth                   Available
            [ ] Windows Authentication                  Web-Windows-Auth               Available
        [ ] Application Development                     Web-App-Dev                    Available
            [ ] .NET Extensibility 3.5                  Web-Net-Ext                    Available
            [ ] .NET Extensibility 4.6                  Web-Net-Ext45                  Available
            [ ] Application Initialization              Web-AppInit                    Available
            [ ] ASP                                     Web-ASP                        Available
            [ ] ASP.NET 3.5                             Web-Asp-Net                    Available
            [ ] ASP.NET 4.6                             Web-Asp-Net45                  Available
            [ ] CGI                                     Web-CGI                        Available
            [ ] ISAPI Extensions                        Web-ISAPI-Ext                  Available
            [ ] ISAPI Filters                           Web-ISAPI-Filter               Available
            [ ] Server Side Includes                    Web-Includes                   Available
            [ ] WebSocket Protocol                      Web-WebSockets                 Available
    [ ] FTP Server                                      Web-Ftp-Server                 Available
        [ ] FTP Service                                 Web-Ftp-Service                Available
        [ ] FTP Extensibility                           Web-Ftp-Ext                    Available
    [ ] Management Tools                                Web-Mgmt-Tools                 Available
        [ ] IIS 6 Management Compatibility              Web-Mgmt-Compat                Available
            [ ] IIS 6 Metabase Compatibility            Web-Metabase                   Available
            [ ] IIS 6 Scripting Tools                   Web-Lgcy-Scripting             Available
            [ ] IIS 6 WMI Compatibility                 Web-WMI                        Available
        [ ] IIS Management Scripts and Tools            Web-Scripting-Tools            Available
        [ ] Management Service                          Web-Mgmt-Service               Available
[ ] Windows Server Essentials Experience                ServerEssentialsRole           Available
[ ] Windows Server Update Services                      UpdateServices                 Available
    [ ] WID Connectivity                                UpdateServices-WidDB           Available
    [ ] WSUS Services                                   UpdateServices-Services        Available
    [ ] SQL Server Connectivity                         UpdateServices-DB              Available
[ ] .NET Framework 3.5 Features                         NET-Framework-Features         Available
    [ ] .NET Framework 3.5 (includes .NET 2.0 and 3.0)  NET-Framework-Core               Removed
    [ ] HTTP Activation                                 NET-HTTP-Activation            Available
    [ ] Non-HTTP Activation                             NET-Non-HTTP-Activ             Available
        [ ] HTTP Activation                             NET-WCF-HTTP-Activat...        Available
        [ ] Message Queuing (MSMQ) Activation           NET-WCF-MSMQ-Activat...        Available
        [ ] Named Pipe Activation                       NET-WCF-Pipe-Activat...        Available
        [ ] TCP Activation                              NET-WCF-TCP-Activati...        Available
[ ] Background Intelligent Transfer Service (BITS)      BITS                           Available
    [ ] Compact Server                                  BITS-Compact-Server            Available
[ ] BitLocker Drive Encryption                          BitLocker                      Available
[ ] BranchCache                                         BranchCache                    Available
[ ] Client for NFS                                      NFS-Client                     Available
[ ] Containers                                          Containers                     Available
[ ] Data Center Bridging                                Data-Center-Bridging           Available
[ ] Enhanced Storage                                    EnhancedStorage                Available
[ ] Failover Clustering                                 Failover-Clustering            Available
[ ] Host Guardian Hyper-V Support                       HostGuardian                   Available
[ ] I/O Quality of Service                              DiskIo-QoS                     Available
[ ] IIS Hostable Web Core                               Web-WHC                        Available
[ ] IP Address Management (IPAM) Server                 IPAM                           Available
[ ] iSNS Server service                                 ISNS                           Available
[ ] Management OData IIS Extension                      ManagementOdata                Available
[ ] Media Foundation                                    Server-Media-Foundation        Available
[ ] Message Queuing                                     MSMQ                           Available
    [ ] Message Queuing Services                        MSMQ-Services                  Available
        [ ] Message Queuing Server                      MSMQ-Server                    Available
        [ ] Directory Service Integration               MSMQ-Directory                 Available
        [ ] HTTP Support                                MSMQ-HTTP-Support              Available
        [ ] Message Queuing Triggers                    MSMQ-Triggers                  Available
        [ ] Routing Service                             MSMQ-Routing                   Available
    [ ] Message Queuing DCOM Proxy                      MSMQ-DCOM                      Available
[ ] Multipath I/O                                       Multipath-IO                   Available
[ ] MultiPoint Connector                                MultiPoint-Connector           Available
    [ ] MultiPoint Connector Services                   MultiPoint-Connector...        Available
    [ ] MultiPoint Manager and MultiPoint Dashboard     MultiPoint-Tools               Available
[ ] Network Load Balancing                              NLB                            Available
[ ] Peer Name Resolution Protocol                       PNRP                           Available
[ ] Quality Windows Audio Video Experience              qWave                          Available
[ ] Remote Differential Compression                     RDC                            Available
    [ ] Feature Administration Tools                    RSAT-Feature-Tools             Available
        [ ] BitLocker Drive Encryption Administratio... RSAT-Feature-Tools-B...        Available
        [ ] DataCenterBridging LLDP Tools               RSAT-DataCenterBridg...        Available
        [ ] Failover Clustering Tools                   RSAT-Clustering                Available
            [ ] Failover Cluster Module for Windows ... RSAT-Clustering-Powe...        Available
            [ ] Failover Cluster Automation Server      RSAT-Clustering-Auto...        Available
            [ ] Failover Cluster Command Interface      RSAT-Clustering-CmdI...        Available
        [ ] IP Address Management (IPAM) Client         IPAM-Client-Feature            Available
        [ ] Shielded VM Tools                           RSAT-Shielded-VM-Tools         Available
        [ ] Storage Replica Module for Windows Power... RSAT-Storage-Replica           Available
            [ ] AD DS Tools                             RSAT-ADDS                      Available
                [ ] Active Directory Administrative ... RSAT-AD-AdminCenter            Available
                [ ] AD DS Snap-Ins and Command-Line ... RSAT-ADDS-Tools                Available
            [ ] AD LDS Snap-Ins and Command-Line Tools  RSAT-ADLDS                     Available
        [ ] Hyper-V Management Tools                    RSAT-Hyper-V-Tools             Available
            [ ] Hyper-V Module for Windows PowerShell   Hyper-V-PowerShell             Available
        [ ] Windows Server Update Services Tools        UpdateServices-RSAT            Available
            [ ] API and PowerShell cmdlets              UpdateServices-API             Available
        [ ] DHCP Server Tools                           RSAT-DHCP                      Available
        [ ] DNS Server Tools                            RSAT-DNS-Server                Available
        [ ] Network Controller Management Tools         RSAT-NetworkController         Available
        [ ] Remote Access Management Tools              RSAT-RemoteAccess              Available
            [ ] Remote Access module for Windows Pow... RSAT-RemoteAccess-Po...        Available
[ ] RPC over HTTP Proxy                                 RPC-over-HTTP-Proxy            Available
[ ] Setup and Boot Event Collection                     Setup-and-Boot-Event...        Available
[ ] Simple TCP/IP Services                              Simple-TCPIP                   Available
[ ] SMB Bandwidth Limit                                 FS-SMBBW                       Available
[ ] SNMP Service                                        SNMP-Service                   Available
    [ ] SNMP WMI Provider                               SNMP-WMI-Provider              Available
[ ] Software Load Balancer                              SoftwareLoadBalancer           Available
[ ] Storage Replica                                     Storage-Replica                Available
[ ] Telnet Client                                       Telnet-Client                  Available
[ ] VM Shielding Tools for Fabric Management            FabricShieldedTools            Available
[ ] Windows Internal Database                           Windows-Internal-Dat...        Available
    [ ] Windows PowerShell 2.0 Engine                   PowerShell-V2                    Removed
    [ ] Windows PowerShell Desired State Configurati... DSC-Service                    Available
    [ ] Windows PowerShell Web Access                   WindowsPowerShellWeb...        Available
    [ ] .NET Environment 3.5                            WAS-NET-Environment            Available
[ ] Windows Server Backup                               Windows-Server-Backup          Available
[ ] Windows Server Migration Tools                      Migration                      Available
[ ] Windows Standards-Based Storage Management          WindowsStorageManage...        Available
[ ] WinRM IIS Extension                                 WinRM-IIS-Ext                  Available
[ ] WINS Server                                         WINS                           Available
```

Comment: What roles are you looking to implement? It appears a lot of the old features connected to NPS are depreciated in Server 2016.

"Network Access Protection (NAP), Health Registration Authority (HRA), and Host Credential Authorization Protocol (HCAP) were deprecated in Windows Server 2012 R2, and are not available in Windows Server 2016. If you have a NAP deployment using operating systems earlier than Windows Server 2016, you cannot migrate your NAP deployment to Windows Server 2016."

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/technologies/nps/nps-top

Comment: I want to use the NPS as a RADIUS server for VPN and 802.1X authentication

Comment: What do you get if you run Get-Windowsfeature -computername domain | where {$_.Installed -eq $false} ?

Comment: What version of Server 2016 are you using (besides datacenter)? All recent updates installed? I had a similar problem some time back with server 2012R2 (I think). After installing all updates in went away.

Comment: @digitalPhonix You're also missing the `Fax Server` role. Can you confirm you are using an unmodified image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This role is not available in Windows Server Core. You must reinstall your server and choose the Desktop Experience version during the setup.

Comment: I don't see anywhere in the screenshot where it suggests that the machine is running Server Core.

Comment: In fact, there are a number of roles listed in the screenshot that are not available on Server Core.

Comment: This was the problem!

Comment: @Davidw what roles are there that shouldn't be?